# ubuntu 20.04 imposible to turn on LivePatch require an internet connection

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 I came from Ubuntu 19.10 and before 18.04, I was using Livepatch in the past.
I fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm facing this message.
[image]

I have an internet connection and is not slow.

I have the OS up-to-date

I just find this article I follow step by step [How to enable Canonical Livepatch from the command line](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-canonical-livepatch-from-the-command-line/)

[image]

But in the Software & Updates
[image]

Comment: So while you captured the image, internet is working.. Is that rite?

Comment: Yes, My internet is working fulltime, I even set up a proxy to the OS to try to use another IP but was useless.

Comment: It seems turning it (live-patch) is bit tough.. I mean after several attempts I got it on in the past with 20.04 fresh install.. In your case it seems you tried hard without success.. Have you gone through manual pages if there is a way via cli?

Comment: @PRATAP Thanks I just update my question I think now I have a different problem because in the CLI I see my LivePatch enable but in the visual is still disabled

Comment: I would not trust the visual and trust what the CLI says.  I usually *only* enable Livepatch via the Command Line, because normally in the GUI it doesn't have the proxy configurations stored in it.  (You'd have to set that up in your network connection settings)  If you did your proxy setup on the command line but NOT in Network Manager GUI you will run into the problem of GUI apps not knowing to proxy out to the net

Comment: Snap is completley different concept..if possible undo those changes.. I am trying to reproduce the issue but no.. In my pc it is asking sign in which means internet step is a success.. I am searching CLI..

Comment: @PRATAP The Livepatch utility is only distributed a snap.  There is no other integrations.  The issue is network configuration - GUI vs. CLI, the GUI doesn't read the HTTP_PROXY, etc. configs on the command line

Comment: Noted.. I think you can answer now @ThomasWard.. Thank You..

Comment: With or without the proxy on the OS or CLI the visual still show the message no internet connection. ):

Comment: @YoandryCollazo how exactly is your system set up?  Does it *need* a proxy or no?  If the system has to pass through a proxy then you *do* have to configure it.  IF not, then you need to make sure the GUI system actually can reach it's connectivity tests, that's a different issue.  However, in either case, trust what the CLI says not the GUI

Comment: @ThomasWard My system does not need the proxy to have the Internet, I only mention the proxy because it was a test case in my research but I don't need proxy to have internet.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of 'how is your system set up' because it's possible you're on a network connection that is fubar and the GUI hasn't 'pinged back' yet.  Or you need to reboot since you just installed it.

Comment: I installed the system 3 weeks ago and restarted many times, about my network connections is not fubar, It is ok, I'm using mobile 4G

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before.

I think this command resets the Livepatch and solved the problem:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier show-livepatch-status-icon true
```

If you already see the Livepatch status icon in the top bar, you can use this command instead:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier show-livepatch-status-icon false
```

If none of the above commands solve the problem, try these:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
sudo systemctl restart netpanel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable livepatch attaching your marchin

go to https://ubuntu.com/advantage#livepatch

copy the command:

```
sudo ua attach <your-token>
```

It will enable livepatch and other services that you can disable later